# formmail to email in database

Tags: php, sql

Here's what I need to setup...and I am not well versed in PHP/SQL...but this is what I'm trying to do.

On the New User database, I will have a section where they can have information sent to their phone using the provider's default e-mail to text msg (i.e. 2225551212@txt.att.net.)

```
New User: 
Input number: ______________(2225551212 format, no hyphens, etc.)
Select Provider: (Drop-down menu with proper @provider.ext...)
```

Then the formmail, when sent, if for specific user will get ($phone".@."$provider); or something like that and send a preset message like:
$user."requested information on ".$product."on".$date." at ".$time.".";

Is this possible?

The $user, $product, $date, $time all are generated directly from the most recent input page for a database.

Is this possible?

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your question is "can I send a text message from PHP", then yes; if the server where you are running PHP is configured to send email, then within PHP you can try:

mail('2225551212@txt.att.net', 'New User', $user."requested information on ".$product."on".$date." at ".$time.".");

For more help with the mail() function, check out http://php.net/mail .